# Understanding the Proof of Strong Normalization of the Calculus of Constructions

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, typed-lambda-calculus

I have difficulties in understanding the proof of strong normalization for the calculus of constructions. I try to follow the proof in the paper of Herman Geuvers "A short and flexible proof of Strong Normalization for the Calculus of Constructions".

I can follow the main line of reasoning well. Geuvers constructs for each type $T$ an interpretation $[\![T]\!]_\xi$ based on some evaluation of type variables $\xi(\alpha)$. And then he constructs some term interpretation $(\!|M|\!)_\rho$ based on some evaluation of term variables $\rho(x)$ and proves that for valid evaluations the assertion $(\!|M|\!)_\rho \in [\![T]\!]_\xi$ for all $\Gamma\vdash M:T$ holds.

My problem: For easy types (like system F types) the type interpretation $[\![T]\!]_\xi$ is really a set of terms, so the assertion $(\!|M|\!)_\rho \in [\![T]\!]_\xi$ makes sense. But for more complex types the interpretation $[\![T]\!]_\xi$ is not a set of terms but a set of functions of some appropriate function space. I think, I almost understand the construction of the function spaces, however it cannot assign any meaning to $(\!|M|\!)_\rho \in [\![T]\!]_\xi$ for the more complex types $T$.

Can anybody explain or give links to some more understandable presentations of the proof?

Edit: Let me try to make the question clearer. A context $\Gamma$ has declarations for type variables $\alpha:A$ and object variables. A type valuation is valid, if for all $(\alpha:A) \in \Gamma$ with $\Gamma\vdash A:\square$ then $\xi(\alpha) \in \nu(A)$ is valid. But $\nu(A)$ can be an element of $(SAT)^*$ and not only $SAT$. Therefore no valid term evaluation can be defined for $\rho(\alpha)$. $\rho(\alpha)$ must be a term and not some function of a function space.

Edit 2: Example which does not work

Let's make the following valid derivation:
$$
\begin{array}{llll}
[] &\vdash  & *:\square &\text{axiom} 
\\
[\alpha:*] &\vdash& \alpha:* &\text{variable introduction}
\\
[\alpha:*] &\vdash& *:\square &\text{weaken}
\\
[] &\vdash & (\Pi \alpha:*.*):\square   &\text{product formation}
\\
[\beta:\Pi \alpha:*.*] &\vdash& \beta:(\Pi \alpha:*.*) &\text{variable introduction}
\end{array}
$$

In the last context a valid type evaluation must satisfy $\xi(\beta) \in \nu(\Pi \alpha:*.*) = \{f| f:\text{SAT} \to \text{SAT}\}$. For this type evaluation there is no valid term evaluation.

Comment: Half the people reading this will think that $SAT$ is SAT. You should explain what it is. Also, your derivation seems a bit odd. The second line should not mention $\alpha$ in its conclusion, it shoudl read something like $[\alpha : *] \vdash * : \Box$, should it not?

Comment: I am using the notation of Herman Geuvers (which seems to be standard in this domain).  $\text{SAT}$ is the set of all saturated sets of lambda expressions. For the second line of my derivation: Its the introduction rule for variables of a pure type system. This rule reads $\frac{\Gamma \vdash T:s}{\Gamma,x:T\vdash x:T}$ where $s$ is some sort.

Comment: I understand how you got the second line but it is not the correct premise for the formation of the third line, is it? What rule gives the third line.

Comment: The product formation rule of PTS says $\frac{r(s_1,s_2,s_3;\, \Gamma\vdash A:s_1;\: \Gamma,x:A\vdash B:s_2}{\Gamma\vdash (\Pi x:A.B): s_3}$. The calculus of constructions has the rule $r(*,*,*)$. This allows me using the first and the second line to derive the third. However I had a typo in my post. The type in the third line had been missing which I added now.

Comment: Shouldn't then the first line read $[] \vdash * : *$? Or did you mix up $*$ and $\Box$ somewhere? The second line cannot be the second premise to the product formation rule, because that would mean you're trying to form something like $\prod \alpha : * . \alpha$ instead of $\prod \alpha : * . *$.

Comment: I have used the weakening rule implicitly which I have now made explicit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure there are more beginner friendly resources than Geuvers' account. You might try [this](http://prosecco.gforge.inria.fr/personal/hritcu/temp/snforcc.pdf) note from Chris Casinghino which gives an account of several proofs in excruciating detail.

I'm not sure I understand the gist of your confusion, but I think one important thing to note, is the following lemma (Corollary 5.2.14), proven in the [classic Barendregt text](http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~dreyer/course/papers/barendregt.pdf):

$$\Gamma \vdash M:T\ \Rightarrow\ \Gamma \vdash T:*\mbox{ or }\square $$

This means that while $[\![T]\!]_\xi$ *can* be some complicated function, *if* $\Gamma \vdash M:T$ holds, then $[\![T]\!]_\xi$ *has to be a set of terms*.

This is insinuated in the outline (section 3.1), where $(\!|t|\!)_\sigma\in[\![T]\!]_\xi$ only if $\Gamma \vdash t:T :*$, which lines up with our expectation, which is that the interpretation of a type must be a set of terms, i.e. ${\cal V}(*)\subseteq{\cal P}(\mathrm{Term})$ (indeed, ${\cal V}(*)=\mathrm{SAT}$!)

It's a common situation in type theory that even though we're only *interested* in the "base kind" (here $*$), we still have to define semantics for things at higher kinds (hence the need to introduce $\mathrm{SAT}^*$). Things then work out at the end, because only kind which inhabited by types is $*$ (and $\square$, but that's not really important).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That solves my problem of not understanding the functions used in Geuver's proof. I had already a suspicion from reading and rereading Geuver's paper, but you made it crystal clear.